# mySQL plugin to show database properties

Tags: mysql

In Microsoft SQL Server, you can right click a database and select Properties to view all the properties about the database. I'm getting started with mySQL but am disappointed that no such eqivalent exists. Is there a plugin for mySQL that provides this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Try MySQL workbench its great product

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

Comment: its more reliable and comfortable

Comment: That's what I'm using but it doesn't contain any feature that shows all properties in a  dialog like MS SQL Server.